# R package error messages have missing package names

Tags: r, r-package, installation-package

I have R running with this sessionInfo ->

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 21.04
```

I am running into a problem with trying to install packages. Usually you get error messages that tell you which dependencies may not be present, so you can work on that. But in this case, the actual name of the dependency (and even the package currently being installed) seem to be missing and are replaced with just `â`

Has anyone else faced this issue? How do I solve this?

An example error message:

```
ERROR: dependency â is not available for package â
* removing â

The downloaded source packages are in
        â
Warning message:
In install.packages("Signac") :
  installation of package â had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Without seeing the code you used to generate that error, it's a little difficult to advise well. However, ensure that the package name is a simple `character` and it *"should contain only (ASCII) letters, numbers and dot"* (from [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html)).

Comment: @r2evans , that's exactly the issue. it doesn't depend on the package name. the specific package has entirely appropriate name, as I'd assume do the dependencies that failed here. The issue is that regardless of what the names are, the error message always prints "â" character, rather than the name itself. 

The code I used was just 'install.packages("Signac")'

Comment: It could be a locale-thing, where some seemingly-ASCII letters are actually unicode or utf8. I'm curious, using your version of the package name(s) as `x`, is `identical(x, iconv(x, "latin1", "ASCII//TRANSLIT"))` true? If not, what is `Encoding(x)`? Do the two (`x` and `iconv(.)`) otherwise look the same?

Comment: I can try this and get back to you, but I doubt it will help. As I said, this is entirely independent of x. This shows up regardless of which package I'm trying to install (unless it has no error messages and installs smoothly).

Comment: If that doesn't work, unfortunately my next thought would be to uninstall and reinstall both R and (if you use it) RStudio. A nuclear option with no basis in empirical justification. (But you may want to check your `.Rprofile`, `.Renviron`, and `.Rproj` files just in case something stands out.)